# Email or Something persistent for User signing in via Google+ (Google Game Services)

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games

Is there a way to retrieve a user's email address programmatically when authenticating during the Google Game Play Services sign in process on Android?

Or even if there is some persistent user ID returned with the token?

We are trying to create a scenario where a user can connect or merge many social accounts to a single account.

Comment: not sure if this is good enough, but you can get user accounts like this: Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT); where GOOGLE_ACCOUNT = "google.com", then iterate to array to find the one you want.

Answer (score 3):

[GamesClient.getCurrentAccountName()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#getCurrentAccountName%28%29) returns the logged in user's email address (assuming you have the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique player id by getting the current play from the [Players](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games.html#Players) object:

```
Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mApiClient).getPlayerId()
```